# query parameter change into "query_string" at laravel 5.5 and php 7.4

Tags: laravel

My website uses Laravel 5.5 and PHP 7.4.
Browser should be sending URL and query parameters as shown below,

```
[correct url of my site]?mode=specific&number=ID
```

but my controller receives it like this:

```
[correct url of my site]?query_string=
```

I can confirm this by adding `$request->fullUrl()` into my controller.

Same code works in another environment,
the only difference is `PHP = 7.0` and it does receive correct query parameters.

Comment: Welcome to SO ... sounds like a misconfiguration of the web server for this site ... are you using nginx? if so you are probably missing the `$` in `$query_string`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm using nginx.and your advice is perfect. I miss $ in my nginx config. I setup this server for half a year ago. and I didn't notice this until now.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry bothering SO for such a ridiculous question.
I just miss $ at nginx server configuration

try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?query_string;   <---- wrong

try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;  <---- correct

Half a year ago my server is broke and then I quickly setuped current server and I missed this "$".

Thank you all.

Comment: I just did exactly the same thing and your post saved me!